# How preserve order of LinkedHashMap while serializing to GWT AutoBean?

Tags: java, gwt, linkedhashmap, autobean, insertion-order

I've tried using `Map`, `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` as a type for AutoBean factory and always after serializing it's changing initial elements order.

I don't want to send additional `ArrayList` that will hold the order data. Is there a way to force AutoBean to keep order in a `Map`?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

> The *order* of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on
>   the map's collection views return their elements. Some map
>   implementations, like the TreeMap class, make specific guarantees as
>   to their order; others, like the HashMap class, do not.

GWT doesn't make any alterations to `Map`-based classes. `Map` and many of its subclasses do not keep order of insertion for performance reasons. `LinkedHashMap`, by design, *does* keep its insertion order. That is, of course, assuming you're **starting** with a `LinkedHashMap` and not constructing it from another type of `Map` which may not actually preserve its order during the insertion, causing the `LinkedHashMap` to have a different order than you're expecting.

I'm wondering why you need to keep the initial order anyway, and why are you using `Map` if that's what you want?

Comment: Hi, GWT isn't reordering my LinkedHashMap. But AutoBean does, while serializing map to json. I'm using it to store column_name = row_value pairs, which are taken from grid model and should be imported into DynamicJasper xls report factory as a List of Map <String, String>. I don't want to change that structure for legacy reasons. My current workaround is passing column order as another List<String>. Thanks God, AutoBean serializes list with right order.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, and at least in GWT 2.4, `LinkedHashMap.clone()` in GWT returns a `HashMap`, in contrast to pure Java behavior. AutoBean probably relies on clone() which messes up the order in the end.